# Does a SELECT happen all at once, or progressively

Tags: mysql, select

I have a process which finds a list of files to be deleted using a SELECT `where`delete`= 'Y'`.

I set this process running the other day but it takes a while because it actually does the file deletions too.

And in the middle of its long operation, I was using the application and deleted one more file.

At this point I realised I didn't know if that file would be deleted, because I didn't know if the SELECT would have found all the files at the start, or if it was finding them progressively and would get to my newly-deleted file eventually.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how are you performing file deletions? Directly with mysql? Or do you have a program that utilizes the sql results to determine what to delete?

Comment: This depends a lot (among many other things) on whether you're using InnoDb or MyISAM tables, and if innodb it depends on which isolation levels you run your queries in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on when the SELECT statement was executed, and how your app is written (if it is using an ORM, etc), but I suspect the below analysis is probably valid.

If you have code that's like this:

```
<prepare query>
<execute query>
for each row in <query_result_cursor>
    <delete file>
```

The select will have acquired all it's rows, and if later a row is updated to have Delete='Y', then it won't pick it up.

The key is identifying when `<execute query>` occurs, and when that occurs in relation to your delete.  If `<execute query>` occurs before you deleted the file using your app, it will get picked up in your process.  If `<execute query>` occurs after, it won't pick it up.

The short answer:  *it happens all at once.*